# $\mathbb{Z}_p[\mathbb{Z}/p^{n}\mathbb{Z}]\cong \mathbb{Z}_p[T]/\left((T+1)^{p^n}-1\right)$ as topological rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-rings, topological-rings

Consider the group-ring $\mathbb{Z}_p[\mathbb{Z}/p^{n}\mathbb{Z}]$ with the product topology, and the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}_p[T]/((1+T)^{p^n}-1)$ with the quotient topology, ($\mathbb{Z}_p[T]$ has the $(p,T)$-adic topology).

If $\gamma$ is a generator of $\mathbb{Z}/p^{n}\mathbb{Z}$, then clearly the map:
$$\gamma\mapsto 1+T$$
is a ring isomorphism. My question  is the following: ¿that map is also a homeomorphism? I'm not even sure if $\mathbb{Z}_p[T]/((1+T)^{p^n}-1)$ is Hausdorff. (Maybe i'm giving $\mathbb{Z}_p[T]/((1+T)^{p^n}-1)$ the wrong topology).

Any hint would be greatly appreciated.